# Check the end of a string for valid regex and return the string trimmed of the regex-

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Here is an attempt to explain a bit clearer with code--

```
str = 'testfoostringfoo';
var regex = /foo$/;

if (str.match(regex) == true) {
    str.trim(regex);
    return str; //expecting 'testfoostring'
}
```

I'm looking for the simplest way to accomplish this using only javascript, though jQuery is available. Thanks for your time. :]

---

---

Fully functioning code with the help from @Kobi-

```
var str = 'testfoostringfoo';
var regex = /f00$/;

if (str.match(regex)) {
    str = str.replace(regex, '');
    return str; //returns 'testfoostring' when the regex exists in str
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply `replace`:

```
str = 'testfoostringfoo';
var regex = /foo$/;
str = str.replace(regex, '');
return str;
```

I removed the `if`, `replace` does not affect the string when `regex` is not found.

Keep in mind that [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Match) returns an array of matches (`['foo']`), so the comparison to `true` fails either way: the condition in `if(str.match(regex) == true)` is always false.
You're looking for `if(str.match(regex))` or [`if(regex.test(str))`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).

Note that [`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) is somewhat new in JavaScript, and it doesn't take parameters, it just removes whitespaces.

Comment: Thank you for the behavioral explanations. This performs exactly as I need.

Comment: @Qwiso - No problem! I added some more notes about your `if`, just in case.